# Chained select using library not working for dynamicaly addition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating chained select drop down list for this purpose i am using a library but my function is not working properly ,the  value of first select is getting disabled if i select it for second time or if i select second row of chained select item.Link of library [here](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained).i need it for dynamically generate multiple rows of chained select..my code is given below (it is just a sample to show that this is generated dynamically)..i am also not getting any error.

```
     <html>
        <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.chained.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
       <h4>General Selection</h4>
<table class="tg" id="custom-fields1">
  <colgroup>
    <col class="col-wide" />
    <col class="col-narrow" />
    <col class="col-normal" />
    <col class="col-normal" />
    <col class="col-normal" />
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-hgcj" rowspan="2">
      <br />General Stream With Session
    </th>
    <th class="tg-hgcj" rowspan="2">Subject Combination</th>
    <th class="tg-hgcj" colspan="2">Bank Transaction Details</th>
    <th class="tg-hgcj" rowspan="2">Add More</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td class="tg-093g">Bank Transaction id</td>
    <td class="tg-093g">Bank Transaction date</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-30rh">
      <select id ="general_stream-0" name="general-stream[]"  onclick="">
          <option >B.A. General(Day Shift)</option>
          <option >B.A. General(Day Shift)With Geography</option>
          <option value="B.A. General(Morning Shift)"> B.A. General(Morning Shift)</option>
          <option>B.Sc. General [Pure. Science]</option>
          <option>B.Sc. General[Bio. Science]</option>
          <option> B.Com. General</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-30rh">

          <select name="GeneraSub[]"id="gen_select-0" >
<option value="Bengali,English,Pol.Sc. " class="B.A. General(Morning Shift)"> Bengali,English,     Pol.Sc. </option>
<option value="Bengali,English,Physical Education "class="B.A. General(Morning Shift)"> Bengali,English,     Physical Education </option>
<option value="Bengali,English,Philosophy"> Bengali,English,     Philosophy     </option>        
<option value="Bengali,English,History             "> Bengali,English,     History              
<option value="Bengali,English,     Physical Education  "> Bengali,English,     Physical Education     </option>        
<option value="Bengali,English,     Economics           "> Bengali,English,     Economics            </option>   
<option value="Bengali,English,     Physical Education  "> Bengali,English,     Physical Education    </option>       
<option value="Bengali,Pol.Sc.,     Philosophy         "> Bengali,Pol.Sc.,     Philosophy         </option>   
<option value="Bengali,Pol.Sc.,     History            "> Bengali,Pol.Sc.,     History            </option>     
<option value="Bengali,Pol.Sc.,     Physical Education"> Bengali,Pol.Sc.,     Physical Education</option>         
<option value="Bengali Pol.Sc.,     Economics        "> Bengali Pol.Sc.,     Economics        </option>     
<option value="Bengali Pol.Sc.,     Physical Education  "> Bengali Pol.Sc.,     Physical Education  </option>           
<option value="Bengali,Philosophy,  Economics        "> Bengali,Philosophy,  Economics        </option>  
<option value="English,Philosophy,  Economics        "> English,Philosophy,  Economics         </option>     
<option value="English,Pol.Sc.,     History           "> English,Pol.Sc.,     History           </option>             
<option value="English,Pol.Sc.,     Physical Education "> English,Pol.Sc.,     Physical Education </option>        
<option value="English,Pol.Sc.,     Economics         "> English,Pol.Sc.,     Economics         </option>   
<option value="English,Pol.Sc.,     Physical Education"> English,Pol.Sc.,     Physical Education </option>           
<option value="Bengali,Philosophy,  History           "> Bengali,Philosophy,  History           </option>     
<option value="English,Philosophy,  History           "> English,Philosophy,  History           </option>   
<option value="English,Pol.Sc.,     Philosophy        "> English,Pol.Sc.,     Philosophy        </option>  
<option value="Pol.Sc.,Philosophy,  Economics          "> Pol.Sc.,Philosophy,  Economics          </option>  
<option value="Pol.Sc.,Philosophy,  History"> Pol.Sc.,Philosophy,  History</option>  
</select>


    </td>
    <td class="tg-30rh">
      <input type="text" name="gtran_id[]" id="gtranid-0" onfocus="checkDuplicatesGen(0)"/>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-30rh">
      <input type="text" name="gtran_date[]" />
    </td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addCF1">Add</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The script is

```
        var m = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".addCF1").click(function() {
    $("#custom-fields1").append([
       '<tr>',
    '<td class="tg-30rh">',


    ' <select id ="general_stream-'+m+'" name="general-stream[]"  onclick="">',
         ' <option value="" >B.A. General(Day Shift)</option>',
         ' <option value="" >B.A. General(Day Shift)With Geography</option>',
          '<option value="B.A. General(Morning Shift)"> B.A. General(Morning Shift)</option>',
          '<option value="">B.Sc. General [Pure. Science]</option>',
          '<option value="">B.Sc. General[Bio. Science]</option>',
          '<option value=""> B.Com. General</option>',
      '</select>', 
      '</td>',
      '<td class="tg-30rh">',
       '<select name="GeneraSub[] id= "gen_select-'+m+'" >',
        '<option value="Bengali,English,     Pol.Sc. "class="B.A. General(Morning Shift)"> Bengali,English,     Pol.Sc. </option>',
        '<option value="Bengali,English,     Physical Education "class="B.A. General(Morning Shift)"> Bengali,English,     Physical Education </option>',
        '<option value="Bengali,English,     Philosophy  "class="B.A. General(Morning Shift)"> Bengali,English,     Philosophy     </option>       ' ,
        '<option value="Bengali,English,     History             "class="B.A. General(Morning Shift)"> Bengali,English,     History    </option>      ' ,   
        '<option value="Bengali,English,     Physical Education  "class="B.A. General(Morning Shift)"> Bengali,English,     Physical Education     </option> ',       
        '<option value="Bengali,English,     Economics           "class="B.A. General(Morning Shift)"> Bengali,English,     Economics            </option>',   
        '<option value="Bengali,English,     Physical Education  "class="B.A. General(Morning Shift)"> Bengali,English,     Physical Education    </option> ',      
        '<option value="Bengali,Pol.Sc.,     Philosophy         "class="B.A. General(Morning Shift)"> Bengali,Pol.Sc.,     Philosophy         </option>  ', 
        '<option value="Bengali,Pol.Sc.,     History            "class="B.A. General(Morning Shift)"> Bengali,Pol.Sc.,     History            </option> ',    
        '<option value="Bengali,Pol.Sc.,     Physical Education"class="B.A. General(Morning Shift)"> Bengali,Pol.Sc.,     Physical Education</option>    ',     
        '<option value="Bengali Pol.Sc.,     Economics        "class="B.A. General(Morning Shift)"> Bengali Pol.Sc.,     Economics        </option>     ',
        '<option value="Bengali Pol.Sc.,     Physical Education  "class="B.A. General(Morning Shift)"> Bengali Pol.Sc.,     Physical Education  </option>   ',        
        '<option value="Bengali,Philosophy,  Economics        "class="B.A. General(Morning Shift)"> Bengali,Philosophy,  Economics        </option>  ',
        '<option value="English,Philosophy,  Economics        "class="B.A. General(Morning Shift)"> English,Philosophy,  Economics         </option>  ',   
        '<option value="English,Pol.Sc.,     History           "class="B.A. General(Morning Shift)"> English,Pol.Sc.,     History           </option>   ',          
        '<option value="English,Pol.Sc.,     Physical Education "class="B.A. General(Morning Shift)"> English,Pol.Sc.,     Physical Education </option>   ',     
        '<option value="English,Pol.Sc.,     Economics         "class="B.A. General(Morning Shift)"> English,Pol.Sc.,     Economics         </option>',   
        '<option value="English,Pol.Sc.,     Physical Education"class="B.A. General(Morning Shift)"> English,Pol.Sc.,     Physical Education </option>   ',        
        '<option value="Bengali,Philosophy,  History           "class="B.A. General(Morning Shift)"> Bengali,Philosophy,  History           </option>  ',   
        '<option value="English,Philosophy,  History           "class="B.A. General(Morning Shift)"> English,Philosophy,  History           </option> ',  
        '<option value="English,Pol.Sc.,     Philosophy        "class="B.A. General(Morning Shift)"> English,Pol.Sc.,     Philosophy        </option> ', 
        '<option value="Pol.Sc.,Philosophy,  Economics          "class="B.A. General(Morning Shift)"> Pol.Sc.,Philosophy,  Economics          </option> ', 
        '<option value="Pol.Sc.,Philosophy,  History "class="B.A. General(Morning Shift)"> Pol.Sc.,Philosophy,  History</option>  ',
        '</select>',
      '</td>',
      '<td class="tg-30rh">',
      ' <input type="text" name="tran_id[]" id="gtranid-'+m+'" onfocus="checkDuplicatesHons('+m+')"/>',
      '</td>',
      '<td class="tg-30rh">',
      ' <input type="text" name="tran_date[]" />',
      '</td>',
      '<td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF1">Remove</a>',
      '</td>',
      '</tr>',
    ].join(''));

    $('#gen_select-' + m).trigger('change');

    m++;
  });
  $("#custom-fields1").on('click', '.remCF1', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
});




    //Script for Chained select list in general Selection
    // var i=0;
    //$('#general_stream-'+i).chained('#gen_select-'+i);

    $(function() {
    $('select[name="general_stream[]"]').each(function() {
        var id = this.getAttribute('id');
        $('#gen_select-'+id.substr(15,1)).chained('#'+id); 
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8dyeye6d/)

Comment: i have no knowledge of this plugin. But since you are referring to drop down lists, perhaps an onChange event is more appropriate than an onClick one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the chained select when the page loads, not on a click.

I removed the `onclick` events from the select and changed the JS to:

```
$(function() {
    $('select[name="mark"]').each(function() {
        var id = this.getAttribute('id');
        $('#series-'+id.substr(5,1)).chained('#'+id); 
    });
});
```

This walks over each select with the name 'mark', uses it's id to extract the number (with substr()) and find the corresponding 'series' select to chain it to.

Edit:
For the dynamically added rows the chained select should be initialized when the row is appended.

[See this (edited) fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8dyeye6d/1/)

Comment: thanks but this is not working with dynamically created selected as i have to use  mark[ ] in dynamically created array as i said in question;  i have modified in the question also@jazZRo

Comment: Hi @avi what do mean exactly with a dynamically created array? Are the options inserted dynamically or the select boxes? And how, with ajax?

Comment: i mean that i am generating multiple mark and select  dynamically when user is select add-more button , so i use array subscript to access the values of that field in php.the options are not generated dynamically they are written just like in this question inside select options.So after loading there may be addition of more chained select row

Comment: i have chaged code with the real code and add a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8dyeye6d/) see it now

Comment: @avi You were almost there. See my edit. There are only missing some classes for the options to get the plugin define the contents.